# Is Unauthenticated role mandatory for AWS Cognito?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

The web UI on AWS Cognito kept telling me to create an Unauthenticated role. I do not want any user to use the app without logging in so do I need to create an Unauthenticated role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito will automatically create the roles for you when you create the identity pool, but if you have unauthenticated users unchecked, you can ignore it after that, or even delete it. It won't be used if you only allow authenticated users.

Comment: I used MobileHub so Cognito did not automatically create the Unauthenticated role.

Comment: Got it. If you marked login as required, you should be good. I'm guessing you're talking about the role association banner at the top? If you want it to go away, you can go through it and it shouldn't cause any harm, just make sure to pick the mobile hub role for auth.

Comment: But to explicitly answer your question, it is not required. It's only needed if unauthenticated users are allowed.